# how to make a python function as built-in function or the alike?

Tags: python

I want to test whether modules exists in python or not? but there seems no direct solution, so I wrote a function as below:

vim

I hope everytime I open the python interactive interface, I can simply type

```
test_module(module_name)
```

and thus check whether a module is existent or not.

so how can I make this function as something like built-in function so as to reach my target?

thanks!

Comment: I have an alternative proposal for checking whether a module exists. Type `import myModule`. If it says `ImportError`, then it doesn't exist. You can also see a list of all modules with `help("modules")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html):

```
import __builtin__


def test_module(module_name):
    # do something here


__builtin__.test_module = test_module
```

In Python 3, the module is called [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) instead.

If you want this to be run every time you open your Python interpreter, you can create a `usercustomize.py` module in [`USER_SITE` location](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE); it'll be imported everytime you run Python.

Be careful with expanding the built-ins, however. Adding names there makes them accessible globally by *all* Python code, and if any such code has accidentally or deliberately uses `test_module` where a `NameError` should have been raised, now uses your custom function.

It's much better to put such things into a dedicated module and only import this when you actually need that function. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: you meant if I use __builtin__ module, the function can't be imported everytime I run python? then what is the usage of __builtin__ module?

Comment: No, I mean that if you add the function to `__builtin__` it *may* mask errors.

Comment: I don't understand. what is the relation between my question and "__builtin__ may mask errors"?

Comment: @user3401853: Say you are running code that explicitly tests if `foobar` is set, catches the `NameError` and handles that by setting something. The code **expects** `foobar` not to exist. Then you add `foobar` to the Python built-ins, you now broke that module.

Comment: @user3401853: Adding a new name as a built-in affects **all** Python code, and you cannot always predict how that code is going to handle the new name in the namespace.